# innodb , mysql Indexes difference when adding index

Tags: mysql, innodb

When I am altering one of my MySQL table to add an index I am getting below error in error log.

> Table a/b contains 4 indexes inside InnoDB, which is different from the number of indexes 3 defined in the MySQL

1. What would be the exact root cause of this issue. Is the table not closed properly? I have read altering the table may remove the extra index which is causing the issue and we may create it later. But I want to know the exact reason why this is happening.
2. I am assuming inside innodb 4 indexes means those indexes definition updated in table `.frm` file and `.ibd` file along with `ibdata1`. But what does it mean by "inside mysql"?

Edit (add CREATE)

```
CREATE TABLE b (
    p datetime DEFAULT NULL, 
    q datetime DEFAULT NULL, 
    r bigint(20) NOT NULL, 
    s varchar(25) DEFAULT NULL, 
    t varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL, 
    u datetime DEFAULT NULL, 
    v varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL, 
    w varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL, 
    x longtext, 
    y longtext, 
    z bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL, 
    k bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL, 
    PRIMARY KEY (r), 
    KEY e (z), 
    KEY f (u), 
    KEY g (s)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

Comment: Run `SHOW CREATE TABLE tablename;` and add the output in the question. Probably related to this bug: https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=70654

Comment: Also add the exact version of mysql you use. An upgrade will probably solve the issue, if it's this bug.

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ:i am assuming 'innodb' means 'innodb data dictionary' in this context .Any idea whats the meaning of 'mysql' here..

Comment: I meant you should add the version of MySQL version you run. You can find it by running `select @@version ;` Also what is the exact `ALTER` statement that produces this error?

Comment: I am using mysql 5.5.40 community version. 'alter table table_name add index index_name(column_name)' is the statement i have used.

Answer (score 1):

Try a no-op `ALTER`:

```
ALTER TABLE tablename ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

([Suggested in this forum.](http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?22,430415,430415))

(Edits)

I do not know why the problem happened.

Here is another 'fix' that *might* work:

```
CREATE TABLE b_new LIKE b;
INSERT INTO b_new
    SELECT * FROM b;
RENAME TABLE b TO b_old, b_new TO b;
DROP TABLE b_old;
```

Comment: yes i tried..but the real question is why its happening..and what is `mysql` in this context.